# Correct indention for blank line in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coding-style

Is there a best practice in ruby coding style for the indentation of blank lines? For example, if I have a blank line between two method definitions within a class, should the blank line be indented to the same level as the method definitions, or should it be truly blank?

```
class Foo
  def bar
  end

  def baz
  end
end
```

For a specific example, in the code above, should the line between the `end` of `bar`'s definition and `def baz` lines contain two spaces like the lines above and below it and a newline, or simply a newline?

I've tried googling this question, searching SO, and looking at style guides, but coming up empty. Maybe I'm phrasing it oddly? Does it not matter? Are there differing opinions? Is there a standard within Rails specifically that differs from the broader Ruby community?

Comment: How on earth would anyone even *know* how you've indented your blank lines?

Comment: @Chuck I have vim configured to show an interpunct character (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpunct) wherever there's a trailing space, so I will avoid trailing whitespace. You can often see it in diffs as well.

Comment: It's a blank line which means there is no content. How can you indent no content? Do you mean a line containing only spaces? It's a waste of disk space to store lines containing only spaces, so most people (and style-guides) recommend trimming trailing spaces, which also will strip the spaces from "blank lines".

Comment: It was perfectly clear to me what the OP meant! And apparently I'm not the only one since my answer has been repeated.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I suppose I was considering the indentation to be "leading" whitespace, but since there is no content, it would equally be trailing whitespace, which is obviously evil under other circumstances. Still it would be nice if style guides would point this out...

Comment: Edited question to clarify, but yes, @Tin Man, I did mean a line containing only spaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just about any style guide you look at will tell you to "avoid trailing whitespace", where trailing whitespace is any non-newline whitespace character on a line that is not followed by a non-whitespace character on the same line.

See https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide for example, or [github's internal ruby style guide](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby).

Since a blank line has no non-whitespace characters, any spaces or tabs on a blank line would constitute trailing whitespace, and should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

There's no point in putting whitespace on a line where there's no code and most editors and IDEs are not going to help you do this either.  Have a look at any of the Rails or Ruby source code, which does not do this.